# How to make ssh log in as the right user?

Tags: linux, ssh, user-accounts, openssh

I use ssh on a variety of machines, mainly linux. Accounts on these machines vary in naming scheme: if my name is First Last, then I have accounts: first, flast, last_f, lastf, and sometimes I need to log in as root. For each machine I use, I would like the openssh client to know which account to use when I don't specify on the command line.

So the question is: How do I make `ssh server` Do The Right Thing when a username is not specified?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a `config` file in your home `.ssh` directory, which can specify a default user, identity file etc and assign it to an alias which you can use to connect.

For example, you could put this into the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host example
    HostName example.com
    User first_last
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example_rsa
    Port 22
    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes

Host example2
    HostName example2.com
    User last_first
    # other parameters as needed
```

Then you can just type `ssh example` or `ssh example2` on the command line to connect.

So you can set one up for each machine you want to connect to, with the relevant user. Then just use the aliases to connect without having to specify a user. You can also use a [pattern](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config#PATTERNS) to match multiple hosts.

There's more information, and details of what you can specify in a config file in the [ssh_config man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config).

Comment: i assume you can specify another user/host pair later in the file?  `Host example2/HostName example2.com/User last_first` and such?

Comment: Of course!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Absolutely, you can specify as many as you want in the same .config file. I have over 20 in mine with no issues. I just leave a space between each distinct Host, which probably isn't required, but makes it more readable.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `config` file? Without dot at the beginning?

Comment: @danadam : Yes, you're correct. I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @rich was trying to get you to show another site in your example; hope you don't mind me going ahead and throwing it in.

Comment: Indenting everything but lines that contain "Host foo" greatly helps the maintainability cause.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Considering the is a Linux question, I'd hardly call the OpenBSD's man page the official one. There are options in Linux's *ssh* (e.g., *GSSAPIKeyExchange*) that aren't available in the BSD version.

Comment: @Dennis, you're right about *GSSAPIKeyExchange* not being available in the OpenBSD version, but it seems to be provided by a patch, so it's not in the portable version either. For example [FreeBSD 10](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE) doesn't have it.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: That's another BSD version. It only results in minor differences here (noneof them relevant to the question), but using BSD man pages for Linux distros (and vice versa) is generally a bad idea. For example, the syntaxes of the [BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat "stat(1)") and [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat "stat(1): file/file system status - Linux man page") flavors *stat* are completely different.

Comment: @Dennis, all the other BSDs use the portable version too. Heck, there's even a [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) that doesn't mention *GSSAPIKeyExchange*.
I agree about being careful about mixing BSD man page with Linux ones.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change it for EVERY site:

Edit your `~/.ssh/config` to have this:

```
Host *
    User buck
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Rich Adam's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/64996/how-to-make-ssh-log-in-as-the-right-user/65001#65001) I found out for PuTTY where it stores its settings.

It's all stored in a registry tree, you'll find it under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham` (Simon Tatham is the developer of PuTTY).
There you can see how a host is defined.