# change default username when ssh to another pc

Tags: ssh, openssh, username

When I `ssh` between different pcs I can omit my username (`tom`) and just type

```
ssh pc_name
```

instead of

```
ssh tom@pc_name
```

I like this feature, and have got into the habit of using it.

Unfortunately, on one of my computers I went for the user name `tommy`.  Everytime I connect to this computer I forget to write `tommy@creative_pc` and wonder why my password doesn't work.  Is there a way to tell ssh what user name to use when the username is omitted?

**Edit:** Just found the following question that is similar: [How to make ssh log in as the right user?](https://superuser.com/questions/64996/how-to-make-ssh-log-in-as-the-right-user)  It didn't come up on my initial search.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sure:

```
$ ssh -l tommy
```

will log you in as tommy.

You can also make this persistent per-host by having a record like this in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host creative_pc
User tommy
HostName creative_pc # put the full host name here or the IP if it is static
```

then you just do:

```
$ ssh creative_pc # this is the string from Host setting
```

and you login there as tommy by default

Comment: Perfect response. @Tom - if you want more info, this is discussed in the ssh man page: http://linuxmafia.com/pub/os2/stahl-ssh/snafu-mirror/ssh.html

Comment: For those of you wanting a default login-user for ALL remote servers. Use '*' as Host wildcard (Host *).

Comment: For myself, I have a single User line in the file and this set it globally. No Host required.

Comment: I believe the "HostName" field is optional. It was for me. Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/64996/how-to-make-ssh-log-in-as-the-right-user/1484694#1484694 is the only appropriate answer.

Answer (score 7):

I have a large list of servers, so I used a shell alias to set a default user for all hosts.
Put bellow line on your ~/.bashrc:

```
alias ssh="ssh -l default_user"
```

You can still set another user, using -l:

```
ssh server -l other_user
```

I started using today, seems working fine on Ubuntu 12.

Comment: Here's a much better way to do it: https://superuser.com/questions/64996/how-to-make-ssh-log-in-as-the-right-user/1484694#1484694